# Access Query assistance

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called SOLDIER INFO I have a field in that table called ORDER NUMBER. I want to update everywhere ORDER NUMBER is.  You see that column is based on julian days and have been populating like 5, 15, or 152.  I need it to populate like 005 or 015, obviously 152 is good.

Basically I need the field ORDER NUMBER to always be 3 digits.  It will never be null. But I need it to be 001, 008, 015, etc instead of 1, 8, 15.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know access SQL syntax, and it would help you to get a better answer if you included your table structures, etc.  Also, the code for any query you tried.  But here is the idea of what you need to do to accomplish your task.  Take the `RIGHT` 3 of the concatenation of '000' (really you could do '00', but if you use 3 zeros and you do have any nulls then the value will be '000') and the value already in [ORDER NUMBER].  Anything with a length of one will then have 2 leading zeros, length of 2 will have 1 leading and 3 will still look the same.  You can eliminate anything that is already 3 chars in your `WHERE` clause with the `LEN` (Length) function.  I did google to see that both `LEN` and `RIGHT` are access functions.

```
UPDATE [SOLDIER INFO]
SET [ORDER NUMBER] = RIGHT('000' + [ORDER NUMBER],3)
WHERE LEN([ORDER NUMBER]) < 3
```